# CakePHP not load views

Tags: php, cakephp

My layout is divided into 3 parts, Header, Content, Footer.

Sometimes when I load a page the cake just returns the Content, or does not load CSS, JavaScript, and the like.

Has anyone had any similar problem?

Comment: Is this on certain pages or at random intervals?

Comment: not enough evidence to seek answers :/

Comment: So far only occurred in two areas of the site, and with a very large attendance.

Comment: This link has a SS
https://ppivot.basecamphq.com/projects/5664808/file/66636055/image003-1.png

Link: http://www.ciauniao.com.br/receitas/bolo-de-chocolate-com-coco/page:85

Answer (score 0):

I took a look on the links in your last comment. They both are password protected, although for me the problem is not in cake, rather than in the assets. Actually I just seen this problem in the first load of the page and then the browser cached the resources and couldn't see this any more.

What I mean is that:

https://asset0.basecamphq.com/sprockets.js?1291422605 took 1.53 sec to load
https://asset1.basecamphq.com/stylesheets/print/application.css?1291422668 845 sec to load

I suppose that sometimes they just doesn't load at all.

I see that these files are on separate domain from the app. If you move these files on the same domain this would improve the performance.

Comment: Prints.


http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/4532/image00112.png
http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8581/image0031.png
http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/5186/image004lc.jpg

Comment: as far I can see it show elements but not the CSS styling. As I told you just try to move the css files on the same server.

Comment: The CSS are on the same server, which he carried was a view that contains the header